# What is the best way to get Facebook Connect going with a Django app? (Given the new data permissions.)

Tags: javascript, python, django, facebook

I'm new to Django and trying to set up a Facebook connected site.  There seem to be three available options at the moment:

1. Use middleware with [PyFacebook](http://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/).  I was able to get the [django-facebookconnect](http://github.com/ryanmark/django-facebookconnect) app going fairly easily and mod it to suit my needs, but it is currently unclear whether PyFacebook even supports extended permissions / if PyFacebook is still even under development?
2. Do everything with javascript.  Teebes' javascript only [django-facebookconnect](http://github.com/teebes/django-facebookconnect/) seems promising along with reviewing the updated [facebook authentication guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)
3. Roll my own Python code a la [Facebook's example](http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/oauth/facebookoauth.py)

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?  I plan to have users authenticate only through Facebook connect and then maintain dummy Django user accounts for each on the backend.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I plan to have users authenticate only through Facebook connect and then maintain dummy Django user accounts for each on the backend.

Seems you want exactly what http://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration does